# Database encoding VisualStudio

Tags: mysql, sql, database, asp.net-core, encoding

How do I change encoding of my database ? Project is NET.CORE 2.1

I tried :

```
ALTER DATABASE DBNAME CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

But VisualStudio did not accept that command, due to syntax Error

The second thing I tried was to change *appsetting.json* by adding `Charset=utf8` to *ConnectionString*.

That did not work either. VisualStudio could not work out *Charset keyword*.

Are there any other ways to do that ? Or is there any mistake in my command ?

Command :
[image]

Comment: Show us please the asp code and the complete error message

Comment: Changing the default charset for the database does very little.  If you are having trouble with garbled characters, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: Eventually, I solved it by adding "N" in fron of text string whithing my sql command.